# What does "relative to 1% of" means?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

This is a part of an assignment from an HTML course that I'm taking.
**If you don't know what "viewport" is:** *"It's the area of the screen in a browser which can display a website without the need to provide scroll-bars."*

*"The vh unit stands for viewport height and is **relative to 1% of the height** of the viewport. It is time to spruce the project up with some CSS. Begin by giving the body a width of 100%, and a height of 100vh."*

**"Relative" in this context has to mean "equal"** otherwise, the sentence **wouldn't make sense** but the usage is somewhat enigmatic to me. I think I got it but I'm not sure. Based on these two definitions from Cambridge Dictionary and Merriam-Webster respectively...

*"having a particular characteristic or value compared to other things of a similar type"*

*"being such only when compared to something else" (one of the synonyms **"equal"** as this is an entry from the thesaurus)*

...does the sentence mean: "The vh unit stands for viewport height and **is a single unit only when compared to 1% of the height of the viewport."**????

Comment: It seems to mean that 1vh = 1% of the height of the viewport.  But you'd get a better answer if you asked in specialist forum not on the general English, since you don't **actually** care what the description means.  You only care about what 1vh is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because *all* instances of the cited text in Google Books say [*The vh unit stands for viewport height, and **it's equivalent to 1/100 of the viewport,** or browser window's, height.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22vh+unit+stands+for+viewport+height+and%22) We're being asked to analyze withdrawn / revised phrasing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd agree with you if the original was *wrong* or was a misquotation, but it isn't. The OP has encountered some perfectly valid English text and wants to understand it.

Comment: @Astralbee: I don't think it ever was "valid" (and presumably the writer and/or his proofreader agree with me). Clutching at straws to "explain" rejected initial phrasing seems pointless to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So if somebody had a question about some text from a first edition book you would refuse to help on the basis that a second edition existed?

Comment: @Astralbee: My degree is in Literary Studies, so I naturally take an interest in the creative process and redraftings. But this site is for teaching the basics of English to non-native speakers, so it's rarely worth going into detail about usages that even an average native speaker wouldn't understand with ease. We have ELU and SE.writing for stuff like that.

Comment: @James K: The only thing I care is the usage of the phrase "relative to" and how it is used so I can understand English better. Or whether it is used correctly or not. I know that 1vh = 1% of the viewport*(I figured it off of the context)

Comment: Unfortunately, the text is just poorly written. I edit books and courses like this and would completely rephrase that content. (Not to mention that setting 100vh on the **body** element isn't a good practice either!) 1vh unit equals 1% of the height of the viewport, so 100vh sets the element to the full height of the viewport (as others have said).

Answer (score -1):

'*Relative*' in this kind of context means *considered in comparison or relation to something else.* Saying "*[x] is relative to [y]*" basically means that [x] *equals* [y], but in a *relative context*. It isn't telling you that one *value* corresponds to another (for example that 12 inches equals 30 centimetres) but that that one measurement *relates to* a percentage, which in turn is only calculable with other measurements.

Your text says that *1vh unit* means *1%* of the viewport (the area in computer graphics being currently viewed). Because the viewport can be any size from a graphical perspective, and the perceived size of that would be relative to things such as your screen size and resolution settings, it would be impossible to relate these units to a physical unit of length, but it is possible to equate it to a *percentage* which is a relative value.

Consider the question of "*how much fuel does a car use?*" There isn't a single measure or numerical value you could respond with, but you could say that it is *relative* to the engine size, and the speed at which the car is moving. You could probably respond, not with a value, but with an equation.

Comment: 1. fuel consumption is relative to the size of the engine means: as the engine gets bigger the fuel usage increases.  But this doesn't work with the sentence in question. It would if the sentence was *"The vh unit stands for viewport height and is relative to the height of the viewport."* **(not "relative to 1% of the height" )** It seems to me that the sentence only makes sense if we assume that **"vh unit"** is regarded literally as a single unit and it's value equals "one" only in relation to "1%" to other value which is the "height of the viewport".

Comment: @StaticBounce No, you're quite wrong. Fuel consumption is not directly proportionate to engine size... it is relative to speed, gear ratio, as well as other factors such as drag. You couldn't directly relate a particular engine size to a value of miles to the gallon. When car manufacturers do, there is a mountain of small print explaining that that is average use in normal conditions etc. Likewise, you couldn't say that a graphic took up an inch on a computer screen because if you doubled the size of the screen it would take up 2 inches. This is relativity.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't make sense to say "The vh unit is equal to 1% of the height". To use the word "equal", it would make more sense to say: "***1*** vh unit is equal to 1% of the height".

The term "relative" is used instead of "equal" as the phrase compares the actual unit "vh", instead of "1 vh".